# Windows 8 Javascript reading html into data.js

Tags: windows-8

I'm using the sample grid javascript template to build a win8 application.

I'm also using the data.js file to load data. However this uses :

`var content = "test content";`

```
var sampleItems = [
{group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Title", description: "DESC", content: content},
```

However, my content text is getting longer and I would also like to put in html syntax like IMG and P etc.

Whats the simplest way to load a local html file into the content variable above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To read an HTML file in the local storage of the application you would use the readText method of the WinJS.Application.local object.

```
var loc = WinJS.Application.local;
loc.readText("fileName", "failed").done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );
```

For reading a file stored in the app package you would execute something more like this:

```
var myText;

var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appx:///html/filename.html"); 
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(url).then(function (file) { 
    Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (text) { 
        myText=text;
    }); 
});
```